# Validity of Schengen Visa after Change of Country of Residence (UAE)

Tags: schengen, eu, uae, valid

Can I travel to Schengen country if I received Schengen tourist visa as a resident of UAE? But before travelling I have to cancel my UAE residency visa and I am not going to return to UAE.

Answer (score 1):

A Schengen Visa is not invalidated when the applicant changes their residence country. There are eleven reasons given for revoking Schengen Visas, change of country of residence at is not listed as one of them. It is not a material change of circumstances.

> REVOCATION OF AN ISSUED VISA
>
> **Legal basis**: [REGULATION (EC) No 810/2009 OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL of 13 July 2009
>   establishing a Community Code on Visas
>   (Visa Code), Article 34 and Annex
>   VI](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:243:0001:0058:EN:PDF)
>   - Pages 35 & 36
>
> A visa shall be revoked where it becomes evident that the conditions
>   for issuing it are no longer met.

1. [HANDBOOK FOR THE PROCESSING OF VISA APPLICATIONS AND THE MODIFICATION OF ISSUED VISAS](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf)
2. [REGULATION (EC) No 810/2009 OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:243:0001:0058:EN:PDF)

Comment: Might there be a problem at entry, as OP may have presented tickets to/from country of residence which would no longer be valid and intent/purpose might then be questioned?

Comment: @Giorgio I honestly do not envisage such a problem because it is not a material change. Consular officers are aware that the tickets we purchase after the visa is awarded is typically different from the booking we provide in the application.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the change of residence might be linked to another change that *is* a material change in circumstances such as a change in income and living expenses.

Comment: @phoog I think that starts delving into hypotheticals.

Comment: True, but it wouldn't be surprising for an immigration officer to ask about it, so the traveler should consider the possibility.